# Image Logo CSS on Navbar; Center Positioning

Tags: html, css

## Image Logo CSS on Navbar; Center Positioning

Hi there, I'm working on a project for myself as a skill improvement. So there is a problem, I'm editing the image for the logo on the navbar with the center position and I'm using HTML with a class from CSS, here is the syntax.

```html
<div class="navbar-logo-header">
<img src="uis-logo.png" alt="uis-logo">
</div>
```

```css
.navbar-logo-header {
    width: 10px;
    height: 3px; 
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

The result is that the position is not flexible according to the image I want, I have given other properties and values, the results still fail and fall apart. Maybe can give me tips in the form of additional class properties and values according to what I want? I am very grateful for the help.

This is the result:
https://urlis.net/9pvgrmzk

I hope that it can help and according to my expectations, the position of the logo is flexible and the red line matches the picture I provided.

Comment: This site has been reported as unsafe
Hosted by urlis.net
Microsoft recommends you don't continue to this site. It has been reported to Microsoft for containing phishing threats which may try to steal personal or financial information.

Comment: You haven't mentioned what you needed exactly. please explain the end result you want

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `margin` to `0 auto`:

```css
.navbar-logo-header {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Please also provide a small explanation of how this code answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

**Using display Block**

The margin right auto and margin left auto should be applied on the child element the image or a seperat div wrapped around the image.

Keep in mind that to center display block elements, elements must have a defined width and height

**Using display flex**
Also it would be easier to use display flex with justify content center and align items center on the parent element.

```
.navbar-logo-header {
    width: 10px;
    height: 3px; 
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```